# Not able to split the string properly using Regular Expression in python

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

I'm using a regex pattern to split some strings based on pipe as the delimiter. Most of the strings were able to split correctly as per my requirement, but one type of string is not splitting correctly.

Delimiter I'm considering is pipe and the rule is that if a pipe or other special character such as \ or " is present or enclosed in a double quotes inside the string, then split should not happen there. The regex pattern which I'm using is:

```
pattern = r'"?\|(?!(?:(?<=[A-Za-z]\|)|(?<=[A-Za-z]\\\|))(?=[a-zA-Z]))"?'
```

And some of the input string values are as follows for which it is working as expected:

```
text = r'ced"|"ms|n"|4|98'
print( re.split(pattern, text) )
# => ['ced', 'ms|n', '4', '98']

text = r'ced"|"ms\|n"|4|98'
print( re.split(pattern, text) )
# => ['ced', 'ms\\|n', '4', '98']

text = r'2|dgx|3|abc'
print( re.split(pattern, text) )
# => ['2', 'dgx', '3', 'ksfh']
```

However for the below input string, this regex is not splitting the string as expected.

```
text = r'2|dgx|abc|3'
print( re.split(pattern, text) )
# => ['2', 'dgx|abc', '3']
```

Instead of the above output , I'm expecting the output to be of ['2', 'dgx', 'abc', '3'].
Is there any way by which I can achieve this by somehow modifying the same regex pattern that I'm currently using for rest of the above input strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an extracting approach using

```
"\|"?(.*?)"(?=\|)|([^"|]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yygvvc/2). *Details*:

- `"\|"?` - a `"|` or `"|"` substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `"` - a `"` char
- `(?=\|)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `|` char immediately on the right
- `|` - or
- `([^"|]+)` - Group 2: any one or more chars other than `"` and `|`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/WYwqNy):

```py
import re
rx = re.compile(r'"\|"?(.*?)"(?=\|)|([^"|]+)')
texts = [r'ced"|"ms|n"|4|98',
    r'ced"|"ms\|n"|4|98',
    r'2|dgx|3|abc',
    r'2|dgx|abc|3']
for text in texts:
    print([f'{x}{y}' for x, y in rx.findall(text)])
```

Output:

```
['ced', 'ms|n', '4', '98']
['ced', 'ms\\|n', '4', '98']
['2', 'dgx', '3', 'abc']
['2', 'dgx', 'abc', '3']
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I tried the above approach. But for some of the cases, it's splitting wrongly. See the Python demo https://ideone.com/XuzUci

Comment: @user16240226 Then explain the pattern requirements. I could only find a rule set for the strings you shared in the question.

Comment: 1. Delimiter is "|" or "| or |" or just | for splitting the string.
2. However if pipe is enclosed within a double quotes in between letters in a string, then it should not be matched. Ex: For input r'3|4|"ab|c"' expected output is ['3', '4', 'ab|c']
3. Also if other symbols such as backslash(\) and doublequote (") are present in between letters, then also it should not split string there. values should be retained as it is. Ex: For input as r'2|"s"xv"|3|45' , expected output is ['2', 's"xv', '3', '45'] and for input r'ge|r"|4|"cd\th' , expected output is ['ge|r',  '4', 'cd\\th']

Comment: @user16240226 Also see https://ideone.com/EdAYfY / https://regex101.com/r/bTSVQh/1